# Find the size of smallest set of vertices that every vertex in multigraph is in set, or is connected with at least one vertex contained in set

Tags: algorithm

For a given multigraph find the size of smallest set of vertices such that every vertex in multigraph is in set, or is connected with at least one vertex contained in set.

Can it be solved better than in O(2^n) ?

Comment: What is *n* in *O(2^n)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to optimize it slightly, but generally speaking - you cannot get sub-exponential time, this is the [Vertex Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover), which is known as [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), which means there is no known polynomial solution and the general belief is there is none.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover

As stated already, you can't solve this problem in polynomial time because it is NP-Hard. However, you can write an 2-approximation algorithm that runs in O(n^2) (which you can easily find on google).

Ex: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33735/The-Vertex-Cover-Problem